# how to show a digit by clicking on button in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, click

I need a functionality that will do following:
after clicking on a button (or div, li, etc.), in the page it should show me the value of the button (in cases of div and li it can show some data that is specific for that exact div or li)

view

```
<ul>
<li data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 'some text')">some text</li>
<li data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 'some other text')">some other text</li>
</ul>
<p data-bind='text: typedDigits'></p>
```

viewmodel

```
function AppViewModel() {
this.typedDigits = '';
this.myFunction  = function(data){

    this.typedDigits = ' ' + data;

};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I get the 'data' in myFunction correctly what I'm sending on click, but I don't know how to pass it to typedDigits that it showed me each time I click the button (div, li)...any ideas?

sincerely thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make `typedDigits` a ko observable:

```
function AppViewModel() {
this.typedDigits = ko.observable('');
this.myFunction  = function(data){

    this.typedDigits(' ' + data);

};
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```